# data.table group by with a filter condition

Tags: r, data.table

Given a `data.table` like the one below, I would like to create a new column which is the `value` summed by region, and where `period == 0`.

```
   region period value
1:     US      0    10
2:     US      1    11
3:  Japan      0    12
4:  Japan      1    13
```

The typical `data.frame` approach to this would be to create a separate frame, filter by period, sum by region, and then merge back with the original frame with `region` as the key. I'm wondering if there is a one-line approach in `data.table` using the `data.table` groupby synytax. The closest I've come is the two-line approach below.

```
x1 <- data.table(
  region=c("US","US","Japan","Japan"),
  period=c(0,1,0,1),
  value=10:13)

x1[period==0,value0:=sum(value),by=region]
x1[,value0:=min(value0,na.rm=T),by=region]


   region period value value0
1:     US      0    10     10
2:     US      1    11     10
3:  Japan      0    12     12
4:  Japan      1    13     12
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the "data.table" *way*, but you can try something like this:

```
x1[, value0 := sum(value[period == 0]), by = region]
x1
#    region period value value0
# 1:     US      0    10     10
# 2:     US      1    11     10
# 3:  Japan      0    12     12
# 4:  Japan      1    13     12
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer Ananda's way, but here's an alternative:

```
x1[x1[period==0,sum(value),by=region], value0 := V1, on="region", by=.EACHI]
```

Answer (score 0):

This makes the groupwise scoping more explicit...

```
> x1[,value0:=.SD[period==0,mean(value)],by=region]                                                                                                                                 
> x1                                                                                                                                                                                
   region period value value0                                                                                                                                                       
1:     US      0    10     10                                                                                                                                                       
2:     US      1    11     10                                                                                                                                                       
3:  Japan      0    12     12                                                                                                                                                       
4:  Japan      1    13     12
```

Comment: Note that `.SD` is not optimised for `.SD[x == .]` yet. This'll be much slower (try on bigger data). Also, the OP's requirement is `sum`, not `mean` (IIUC).